# After upgrading Umbraco 6.0 to version 7.3.6, the backoffice does not render any CSS of JS files

Tags: asp.net, upgrade, umbraco7, umbraco6

I have just upgraded Umbraco, gone through 2 days of messing around and have finally managed to get it to upgrade the Db and login to the backoffice, but now there is absolutely no styling on it, and none of the scripts work.

I've read about a lot of people having this same issue, but none of the forums have a definitive answer.

So far I have:
- incremented my ClientDependency version number
- replaced the /Config files
- merged my web.config files
- overwritten the dlls in my /bin with the new files
- overwritten /umbraco and /umbraco_client folders with the new ones
- upgraded my solution from .Net 4.0 to .Net 4.5
- Deleted the /App_Data/Temp folder
- hard refreshed my browser (20 million times)
- pulled out sufficient hair that I could now fashion a luxurious wig

Anyone who can help me, I welcome your input!

Thanks

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? I've just upgraded 7.4.2 to 7.5.3 and am getting this despite a diff showing now differences in the core files. Like you have done every possible cache removal option!

Comment: Added my fix below. Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by installing the `ImageProcessor.Web`. I did this via nuGet package manager as I was using visual studio. The steps I followed were these:

1. Go to Tools > Package Manager Console
2. Once it loads up, type `Install-Package ImageProcessor.Web` and hit enter
3. Check your Web.config - some ImageProcessor paths should have been added right at the end of the file. Also check in the folder `/Config` for a subfolder called ImageProcessor.

Re run the site and the back office should be fixed.

Hope this helps!